# Imprecise window scrolling loop (JS)

Tags: javascript, scroll

In order to make an animated scrolling, I have made a loop that increments ++ the current browser's screen position to reach the value of the offset height of an element in the dom. The problem is that the scrolling seems visually move much further than the increment value. However, an indicator expression shows me the correct value well.

```
function windowScroll(j)
    {
        var actualScrollY;
        var newScrollY;
        actualScrollY = window.pageYOffset;
        newScrollY = document.getElementById(j).offsetTop;

        var i = setInterval (
                function()
                    {
                        actualScrollY++;
                        window.scrollBy(0, actualScrollY);
                        document.getElementById('indicator').textContent = newScrollY-actualScrollY;
                        if  ( actualScrollY > newScrollY ) 
                            { clearInterval(i); }
                    }, 25);
    }
```

Comment: You might be interested in this http://www.surrealcms.com/blog/smoothly-scroll-to-an-element-without-a-jquery-plugin

Comment: Thank you Parchment for that cool link, but my teacher expects me development in pure javascript...